# Getting Empty response From PHP web API in android

Tags: java, php, android, android-asynctask

I'm using Asynctask For network call in android Studio.I have php web API's I dont know why but Some of them Not Working in android .

### Following is My AsyncTask Class...

```
    private class AsyncAddfriend extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url = null;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            url = new URL("http://ishook.com/users/friends/send_friend_request_json/");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);


            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                    .appendQueryParameter("sessionId", params[0])
                    .appendQueryParameter("UserId", params[1])
                    .appendQueryParameter("friendId", params[2]);
            String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(query);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            conn.connect();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

            // Check if successful connection made
            if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                // Read data sent from server
                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

                // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                return (result.toString());


            } else {

                return ("unsuccessful");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "exception";
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }


    }
}
```

---

I'm using same Code for other API's also they all are working fine but this api is not working.
I have Tested This API in post man its working but in not working  android .

Hope You will understand My problem....

Comment: _"Not working"_ is a pretty broad statement. _How_ isn't it working? Errors? Invalid response? Invalid values? App crashes? Phone catches on fire?

Comment: Explain what is happening and what you expect to happen as 'not working' does not describe what we need to look at.

Comment: getting nothing or empty response

Comment: I'm also having Same problem

Comment: i have tested api in post man its working